# pass "key" param to react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass a parameter with name "**key**" to a react component and it does not work. If i use "**keyy**" instead of "key" then it works.

It seems for me that "key" is a restricted keyword and I can not use it as a name of parameter.

Is that true?

That is my example:

```
render() {
   <MyComponent key='apple'
                keyy='pear'>
}
```

Comment: The console should tell you this explicitly when you use a reserved property

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, that is true, **key is a restricted keyword and doesn't get propagated as props.**

---

> Keys serve as a hint to React but **they don't get passed to your components**. If you need the same value in your component, pass it explicitly as a prop with a different name:

```
const content = posts.map((post) =>
  <Post
    key={post.id}
    id={post.id}
    title={post.title} />
);
```

> With the example above, the Post component can read props.id, but not props.key.

Read more in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)

Answer (score 5):

Yes `key` keyword is reserved, this is used by React to identify html elements, it should be unique. It helps to improve the performance. 
We should add a key to each child.
This way React can handle the minimal DOM change.

[From React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html):

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity. Keys used within arrays should be unique among their siblings. However they don't need to be globally unique. Keys serve as a hint to React but they don't get passed to your components. If you need the same value in your component, pass it explicitly as a prop with a different name.

Answer (score 1):

`key` is a reserved word.

From [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys):

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity:
>
> The best way to pick a key is to use a string that uniquely identifies a list item among its siblings. Most often you would use IDs from your data as keys.

[This](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys) is also good and explains why React uses the `key` param, and what are the benefits. You will find that the `key` param is the cornerstone of the React **reconciliation algorithm**.

---

Apart from the `key` param there are few more reserved words you should not use such as:

`ref` and `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

The later one `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` you use instead of DOM `innerHTML`

Check in [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html) for more details.