# Zod & React: 'Key' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, zod

I have the following code set up for a Zod contract, and I'm getting this error message when trying to use Key and ReactElement. I'm not clear on what the solution is in this instance, and other examples of this error message aren't related to a Zod-based error so I'm not sure if they apply. The error I'm getting, I'm getting on both Key and ReactElement.

`'Key' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here`

```
import { z } from "zod";
import { Key, ReactElement } from "react";


export const Foo= z.object({
    key: Key.optional(),
    children: ReactElement.array(),
    catId: z.string().optional(),
    identifier: z.string().optional(),
})

export type FooProps= z.infer<typeof Foo>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you expect key to be or do, as the error says it's just a type and can't be used as a value `type Key = string | number`. It looks like you expect it to be the same API as zod (`.optional()`) but React has nothing to do with zod.

Comment: More clarification is necessary to understand the use case, but `key` is a restricted keyword in React: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41934077/pass-key-param-to-react-component. This may be related to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is achievable. Zod required any value. But react Key, ReactElement etc. are not value, they are type. So. you can't use Key, ReactElement directly in Zod object.

After inferring Zod object, you can extend the inferred type or interface.

I am giving a simple example:

```
import { z } from "zod";
import { Key, ReactElement } from "react";

export const Foo = z.object({
    catId: z.string().optional(),
    identifier: z.string().optional(),
});

export type FooProps = z.infer<typeof Foo>;

export interface FooFinalProps extends FooProps {
    key: Key;
    children: ReactElement;
}

const FooContainer = (props: FooFinalProps) => {
    return (
        <div key={props.key} style={{borderColor: "black", border: "2px", borderStyle: "solid"}}>
            {props.catId && <p>Cat ID: {props.catId}</p>}
            {props.identifier && <p>Identifier: {props.identifier}</p>}
            {props.children}
        </div>
    );
}

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <FooContainer key={1}>
                <p>Variation 1</p>
            </FooContainer>
            <FooContainer key={2} catId="cat2">
                <p>Variation 2</p>
            </FooContainer>
            <FooContainer key={3} identifier="identifier3">
                <p>Variation 3</p>
            </FooContainer>
            <FooContainer key={4} catId="cat4" identifier="identifier4">
                <p>Variation 4</p>
            </FooContainer>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

You can simplified if Key is used in many props.

```
import { z } from "zod";
import { Key, ReactElement } from "react";

export interface CommonProps {
    key: Key;
    children: ReactElement;
}

export const Foo = z.object({
    catId: z.string().optional(),
    identifier: z.string().optional(),
});

export type FooProps = z.infer<typeof Foo> & CommonProps;

const FooContainer = (props: FooProps) => {
    return (
        <div
            key={props.key}
            style={{
                borderColor: "black",
                border: "2px",
                borderStyle: "solid",
            }}
        >
            {props.catId && <p>Cat ID: {props.catId}</p>}
            {props.identifier && <p>Identifier: {props.identifier}</p>}
            {props.children}
        </div>
    );
};

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <FooContainer key={1}>
                <p>Variation 1</p>
            </FooContainer>
            <FooContainer key={2} catId="cat2">
                <p>Variation 2</p>
            </FooContainer>
            <FooContainer key={3} identifier="identifier3">
                <p>Variation 3</p>
            </FooContainer>
            <FooContainer key={4} catId="cat4" identifier="identifier4">
                <p>Variation 4</p>
            </FooContainer>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

The output will be something like this:
[image: Output]