# Why does the event listener not respond when I set the key to a props value?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web

I'm trying to execute a function if the user presses the key presented in the component props

```
const triggerFunc = (e) => {
    if(e.key == props.key) {
      clickFunc()
    }
  }
  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', triggerFunc)
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', triggerFunc)
    }
  }, [])
```

I expected this to work but when I press the key set in it nothing happens although it works fine if I set it to the key literally like this `if(e.key == 'q')`

Comment: Can you console.log(props.key) to confirm that the value is 'q' as you wanted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pass "key" param to react component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41934077/pass-key-param-to-react-component)

Answer (score 1):

`key` is one of the internal attributes/props for react components, You need to change the property name from key to something else and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a simple solution and it was by changing props.key to props.numKey or something